# DirectShow interpolation (pixelization) problem with VMR9 windowless

Tags: resize, directshow, pixel, interpolation, directshow.net

For a .net project, I use DirectShow (through DirectShow.net) with the VMR9 in windowless mode for video display.

On Windows 7, I noticed a pixelization problem when the video is resized (magnified).
I can’t find how to tell the VMR9 to use a specific interpolation algorithm (i.e. bicubic).

It looks like, by default, it uses none.

I would like to avoid using my own allocator-presenter for this task.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the EVR rendered on window7 to avoid pixelated video.

See this question:
[WMV media streams appear more pixelated on Windows 7 than on XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134579/wmv-media-streams-appear-more-pixelated-on-windows-7-than-on-xp)

Evr comes with it's own set of problems, I've found that resizing an EVR rendered stream is slow / jerky.  And EVR is only available on vista and later operating systems.  Stick with vmr9 for xp.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else ;)